# SOAPUI XPath specific value property transfer

Tags: xml, json, xpath, soapui

I have a response where I have many values that are returned. I only want to transfer *one specific* value. How do I go about this?

```
<lookupData>
    <entry>
        <key>CREDITCARD</key>
        <value>
           <item>{"information":"Master Card","nameOnCard":"John","cardNumber":"558732******5605","cardExpiry":"92016","description":"MASTER CARD  5605","verified":"false","pmId":"DxcyAUk9MEE8REp2U2FgUWRdFmVCFH4RX3NUZH9QZ1MYZQ8\u003d","defaultPM":"false"}</item>
        </value>
    </entry>
</lookupData>
```

In the `<item>` tag, I want to transfer only the `pmId`. How do I go about this in *SoapUI*?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In pure XPath, you can use this expression

```
substring-before(substring-after(//lookupData/entry[key="CREDITCARD"]/value/item, ',"pmId":"'), '","defaultPM"')
```

which finds the `item` element in the `lookupData` where `key` is `CREDITCARD` and extracts the *string* between `,"pmId":"` and `","defaultPM"`.

You can also try reading JSON directly with XPath, since [SOAPUI converts JSON to XPath](http://www.robert-nemet.com/2012/08/json-asserting-in-soapui.html). Converting JSON to XML the path would be `//lookupData/entry[key="CREDITCARD"]/value/item/pmId`.

Answer (score 0):

You have JSON embedded in XML. I do not believe there is a way to extract that with pure XPath, unless you want to resort to string manipulation like @helderdarocha suggested.
You could do it in Groovy:

```
def lookupData = new XmlSlurper().parseText("${context.currentStep.name}#ResponseAsXml")
def item = new JsonSlurper().parseText(lookupData.entry.value.item.toString())
// at this point you can access the value
println item.pmId.value
// so you can do something like
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("prop_name", item.pmId.value)
```

There are possibilities to optimize this code, but I hope you get the idea.